# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer on my CS50 Blur Filter

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, cs50

I cant seem to figure out why this error keep happening. I'm fairly new to coding and this program is supposed to blur an image using box blur but I get the error when I try and execute the program. I know it's probably not the most efficient solution but any tips on how I can get it to work would be much appreciated!

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE old[height][width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            old[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    } 
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //top left corner
            if(j == 0 && i == 0)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue) /4);
            } 
            //top right corner
            else if(j == width && i == 0)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue) /4);
            } 
            //bottom left corner
            else if(j == 0 && i == height - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue) /4);
            } 
            //bottom right corner
            else if(j == width && i == height - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen) /4);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue) /4);
            } 
            //first row
            else if(i == 0 && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue) /6);
            }
            //last row
            else if(i == height && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue) /6);
            }
            //first column 
            else if(j == 0 && i > 0 && i < height - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue) /6);
            }
            //last column
            else if(j == width && i > 0 && i < height - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen) /6);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue) /6);
            }
            else if(i < height - 1 && j < width - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (old[i][j].rgbtRed + old[i][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + old[i][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j].rgbtRed + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + old[j-1][i+1].rgbtRed) /9);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (old[i][j].rgbtGreen + old[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + old[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + old[j-1][i+1].rgbtGreen) /9);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (old[i][j].rgbtBlue + old[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + old[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + old[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + old[j-1][i+1].rgbtBlue) /9);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==9889==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fff298bd0b8 (pc 0x000000442a96 bp 0x7fff298bc2b0 sp 0x7fff298071c0 T9889)
==9889==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x442a95  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x442a95)
    #1 0x4232f1  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x4232f1)
    #2 0x7f302ce5db96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x402e19  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402e19)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==9889==ABORTING
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: what is `RGBTRIPLE` ?

Comment: I think I have got one. When height is 1 your third if statement may give error because you are doing ```i-1``` when ```i is 0```. And also your program won't enter some if statements because you have put ```j == width``` it never happens so.

Comment: RGPTRIPLE is a struct holding coloured pixels of an image.

Comment: @Natiloon did you try what I have said and for which input are you getting the error? if you could tell that, it would make work easier and faster

Comment: @SaiSreenivas I am just attempting to fix now. I have changed the j == width statements to say j == width - 1 which should help however the error still appears. By my third If Statement do you mean the if statement for the bottom left corner?

Comment: Not sure if related (actually it very probably is related!), but there are some tests that are always false such as `j == width` for the top and bottom right corner (should be `j == width - 1`) and `i == height` for the last row (should be `i == height - 1`). Also, the `j == width` is wrong for the last column (should be `j == width - 1`).

Comment: @Natiloon yep the bottom left corner one

Comment: @Natiloon also change where you have ```i == height``` to ```i == height - 1``` as @IanAbbottt mentioned. Changing these won't help to fix the error, but the ```bottom left corner``` might be the cause. Just fix that and check once

Comment: @SaiSreenivas to me i == height - 1. so  i - 1 should be okay?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas So i've updated my code on here to reflect the changes you mentioned but i'm still getting the error

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you, i've made those edits. Sadly still an error ;(

Comment: Now for the ```bottom left corner if statement``` , when i is 0, you will get an error because you are doing ```old[i-1][j]``` in that if statement

Comment: @SaiSreenivas so I could fix this by adding  else if(j == 0 && i == height - 1 && i > 0)?

Comment: @Natiloon - I have rolled back your post to just prior to you editing out what is likely a serious contribution to the main issue you are asking about. ( `j == width` to `j == width -1` , etc. ) Please do not edit the post with code corrections that are central to the problem people are helping you to find.  It introduces confusion to the comments, and to the ability of others to help.

Comment: @ryyker ah okay. Sorry!

Comment: No Problem.  Its a common thing for people new to the site to do.  Just not a good idea :)

Comment: @Natiloon yeah that would help, once try with that, till then I'll check if there are any more erroneous things

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Still the same error. it compiles fine but then when I run program the error appears

Comment: I'll edit and post the code. give me a min

Comment: @Natiloon for what values of ```height``` and ```width``` you are getting the error? And also once try running it on online gdb

Comment: Incidentally, assuming `rgbtRed` etc. are integral type, expressions such as `round((a + b + c + d) / 4);` are truncating towards zero before rounding. You should use floating point divisor constants such as `4.0` if you want to round to the nearest integer.

Comment: None of the errors that have been listed in the code would suggest an access violation, if anything, although are they are bugs, they are the type of bugs that inhibit proper execution flow.  (eg expressions that are always `FALSE`). The problem would therefore be in an area of your code that was never posted :)  It is always good to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I cant seem to figure out why this error keep happening."*
(Regarding exception signal: `==9889==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.` )

Although I agree with the suggestions offered in the other answer, it does not address the central issue you asked about, which is likely to be caused by undefined behavior somewhere in your code.

Note: The error statement: `signal is caused by a READ memory access.` is a symptom of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), (UB) for which my [favorite definition](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is apropos to what you are seeing.  Specifically, your code at some point is attempting to write to memory that it does not own. If the un-owned memory being written to happened to be un-owned by any other process, than your program may not have even thrown an exception.  However in your case, it is very likely that the memory your process did not own *was* owned by another process causing the OS to complain and signal an exception that you were trespassing on another's property (memory location).

It is interesting that the code you posted shows no clear signs that an assignment is attempting to access memory that is not owned.  The conditions given to bound the nested loop for all of the assignments:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
```

clearly does not allow `i` or `j` indices to exceed the boundaries of the `image` array.
And the subsequent statements such as:

```
else if(j == width && i == 0)
```

are guaranteed by the conditions in the for loop to never allow `j == width`, thus preventing what *could have been* an attempt to write for example to `image[i][j].rgbtRed` (where if `j == width` would put the array one memory location out of bounds.) and being the cause of the exception.

So I am suggesting that it is possible that the exception occurs due to code not posted. (You never answered the questions in comments of *where exactly* the error occurred.)  You have not found it yet.  It would be a very good move for you to discover the root cause, where ever it is and remove it.

Or, you can post an [minimal but complete, compilable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) thus better enabling others visiting this post to help you find it.

***EDIT*** - I ran your code with just enough of a `main()` function ( see below ) to do it and found no evidence of read memory access violations *in the code snippet that you posted*.  I strongly believe at this point the problem lies else where, perhaps in a section of code you did not include:

```
   typedef struct {
        int rgbtRed;    
        int rgbtGreen;
        int rgbtBlue;
    }RGBTRIPLE;
    

    void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);
    
    int main(void)
    {
        
        RGBTRIPLE image[2][3] = {{{12,13,14},{14,15,16},{15,16,17}},{{16,17,18},{17,18,19},{18,19,20}}};
        blur(2, 3, image);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is a very well described reply and helped me understand what was going on so thank you. Unfortunately this was part of CS50's online problem sets so I didn't write the code on the other documents and don't quite understand it well enough to create a minimal complete example.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to hardcode so many edge cases (literally heh), it's expectable for problems to arise. Why not, instead, try matrix traversal? i.e construct an imaginary matrix, taking the current pixel (`[i][j]`) as center, now traverse all the *valid* pixels of said matrix and add them up. Simple and efficient.

```c
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    RGBTRIPLE old[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Copy the original image over to a temporary variable, row by row
        memcpy(old[i], image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * width);
    }
    // Iterate through rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through columns
        for (int j = 0, red, green, blue, count; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Reset the variables
            red = blue = green = count = 0;
            // Move row-wise in the imaginary matrix (centered around [i][j])
            for (int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)
            {
                // Move column-wise in the imaginary matrix (centered around [i][j])
                for (int c = j - 1; c <= j + 1; c++)
                {
                    // Check for invalid pixels
                    if (r < 0 || r > height - 1)
                    {
                        // Invalid row, no need to continue, move on to next row
                        break;
                    }
                    if (c > -1 && c < width)
                    {
                        // Valid pixel
                        count++;
                        // Sum up every pixel color
                        red += old[r][c].rgbtRed;
                        green += old[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                        blue += old[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Calculate the average and assign
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((float)red / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float)green / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((float)blue / count);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This achieves the same as what you *wanted* to achieve, except by constructing an imaginary matrix around each pixel, and checking *the inner index* of said matrix - we make this problem far simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's going to take me a little bit of understanding as some of this stuff is very new to me and i haven't been coding for long at all but I can already see how this is much better than what I had written!

Comment: @Natiloon I think `memcpy` is the only new thing I introduced here. See the docs [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario where e.g. `j==width-1`, an access to `old[i][j+1]` would go beyond the end of the inner array.  Although the C language designed by Dennis Ritchie allowed for accesses which exceed the bounds of an inner array but end up within an outer array, the Standard allows implementations to trap or behave nonsensically if such accesses are attempted.  I suspect that the UndefinedbehaviorSanitizer is flagging such accesses.